# Does the Jenkins master node store the HTML-formatted console log?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to do some parsing on console logs of Jenkins jobs. In the web UI the standard console log includes a lot of hrefs. I specifically care about links to downstream builds that my pipeline kicks off. The log file stored on the Jenkins master in `/var/jenkins_home/jobs/<my job>` is the plaintext version that you can get from the `/consoleText` endpoint of the job. This does not include any of the hrefs.

Is the HTML console log stored anywhere on the master, or is it generated at the time of request? I'm running this script on the Jenkins master itself, so it seems like a silly extra step if I have to make it hit its own endpoint to get the logs I want.

Answer (score 1):

The raw log (`/consoleText`) resides on the master at:
`${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/[<FOLDER>/jobs/...]/[JOB_NAME]/builds/###/log`

It is a text file. There is no html copy.

There is a System Property to store them elsewhere (a good idea):
[jenkins.model.Jenkins.buildsDir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/#jenkins-model-jenkins-buildsdir)

The following placeholders are supported for this value:

- `${JENKINS_HOME}`  – Resolves to the Jenkins home directory.
- `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}` – The directory containing the job metadata within Jenkins home.
- `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` – The full name of the item, with file system unsafe characters replaced by others.

Comment: Do you know where in code the Jenkins master generates the HTML version that it serves on the `/console` endpoint?

Comment: Try: [`hudson.console`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/tree/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/console)